# Can I safely operate a PLL below it's "minimum" RF frequency?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, pll

I was wondering if anyone has had luck operating a PLL below the spec'd minimum RF frequency. For example, Analog's ADF4107 PLL specs 1-7GHz RF input frequency, but I don't immediately see why it can only operate in that range.

For PLLs with external oscillators, what is really constraining the RF frequency range? Having an upper bound makes sense, but it seems like you should be able to run them (almost) as slowly as you'd like.

Comment: Yes someone had bad luck operating the PLL below that frequency: namely the people who designed it, tested it and built millions of copies. They chose a number for the minimum which avoids the bad luck.  Now these numbers are intended for mass production use of the chip. If you're willing to test individual units, you may be able to stray outside the parameters.

Comment: It's not trivial to make a phase comparator which works over a range of a factor of 2 or more without possibly becoming confused by aliasing.  One which is protected against this may have some frequency-dependent behavior.  Similarly, other parts of the chip may only work "well" in a certain frequency range, and be marginal outside it.  Any plots on the data sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analog devices provide enough range from their pin-compatible PLLs: -

[image]

This little lot cover 50 MHz to 7 GHz.

FYI I've operated the ADF4111 at 70+ MHz and it still worked but that's pushing it I reckon.

Most (if not all applications of PLLs) are on a limited target bandwidth. However, AD do say that the widest bandwidth application is probably cable-TV tuners where it might be about 400 MHz. That's one side of the reason.

The other side of the reason is that VCOs (to maintain their low jitter characteristic) only have as much push and pull range as the application demands. Think of it another way; if the VCO control voltage range was 5V and it gave you a 400 MHz coverage, +/-1mV would give you +/-80kHz of jitter - probably far too much for most applications so, VCO's have a limited range.

Answer (score 0):

The classical trade off is with jitter.  IF you allow the PLL to run slowly you must open up your loop filter.  A wider loop filter means, more noise on the voltage to frequency node, which manifests itself in higher jitter.

So no, it doesn't make sense to have a PLL that runs BOTH slow and Fast.